# Error when attempting to print string from dynamic string array via struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, heap-memory

My program is supposed to get a string from the user via fgets into a dynamic string array (char**) inside a pointer to a struct and then print it.
instead i get an error whenever i print.

In the example i will only print the first part of the list because it sends an error anyways

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct list
{
    char** items;
    int count; //number of items in the list.
}list;
```

The code before i send the "list" to the function that gets the input fro the user:

```
list tempList; // Generic names to demonstrate the case
list *myList = &tempList;

// Resetting the list to default values...
myList->count = 0;
myList->items = (char**)malloc(1); 
//Setting the string array size to 1, later i increase it as i get input from the user

myList = addItem(myList);
```

```
list *addItem(list *myList)
{
    /*
    The function gets a list adds a string from the user and raises the count by 1
    */
    char tempStr[STR_LEN] = ""; //temp string so i can later assign it dynamically 
    int size = sizeof(myList->items); //getting the existing length of the list
    // getting the string
    printf("Enter String:\n"); 
    fgets(tempStr, STR_LEN, stdin);
    //

    myList->items = realloc(myList->items, size + 1); //adds room for 1 more item in the list
    size = size + 1;
    myList->items[size - 1] = malloc(strlen(tempStr)); //accesing the cell and assigning memory 
    strcpy(myList->items[size - 1], tempStr);
    myList->count++;
    return myList;
}
```

finally, printing the item:

```
printf("%s", myList->items[0]);
```

I know this is a lot of code but this is as little as I can show

after getting the input from the user when it should print VS pauses the program and opens stdio.h in a new window saying "Exception thrown: read access violation".

I have never gotten this error before and i couldn't for the life of me figure out what it means.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: `int size = sizeof(myList->items);` is false too, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your errors are :

> ```
>  int size = sizeof(myList->items);
> ```

that does not give the size of the previously allocated dynamic array

use *count* to know the number of element already present

and

> ```
>  myList->items = realloc(myList->items, size + 1); //adds room for 1 more item in the list
> ```

do not realloc enough because the size is not the number of element (there are not *char*), must be :

```
myList->items = realloc(myList->items, (myList->count + 1) * sizeof(char *)); //adds room for 1 more item in the list
```

and you do not need the variable *size*, so (the *malloc* must be the length of the string more 1 for the null character) :

```
myList->items[myList->count] = malloc(strlen(tempStr) + 1); //accesing the cell and assigning memory 
strcpy(myList->items[myList->count], tempStr);
myList->count++;
```

---

Note when you initialize with

> ```
>  myList->items = (char**)malloc(1);
> ```

you can do

```
myList->items = malloc(0);
```

and the *cast* is useless

---

It is useless for *addItem* to return the list because it is always the argument *myList*

---

The code getting all the remarks in account (I also remove the useless *myList* at the beginning)

```
list tempList; // Generic names to demonstrate the case

// Resetting the list to default values...
tempList.count = 0;
tempList.items = malloc(0); 
//Setting the string array size to 0, later i increase it as i get input from the user

addItem(&tempList);
```

and

```
void addItem(list *myList)
{
    /*
    The function gets a list adds a string from the user and raises the count by 1
    */
    char tempStr[STR_LEN]; //temp string so i can later assign it dynamically 

    // getting the string
    printf("Enter String:\n"); 
    fgets(tempStr, STR_LEN, stdin);
    //

    myList->items = realloc(myList->items, (myList->count + 1) * sizeof(char *)); //adds room for 1 more item in the list

    myList->items[myList->count] = malloc(strlen(tempStr) + 1); //accesing the cell and assigning memory 
    strcpy(myList->items[myList->count], tempStr);
    myList->count++;
}
```

Note you do not check the return value of *fgets* (for EOF case) nor remove the probable newline character at the end

Comment: so in order to realloc() enough memory i need to use the size of the tempstr?

Comment: @GiladRaz, I edited my answer : `myList->items = realloc(myList->items, (myList->count + 1) * sizeof(char *)); //adds room for 1 more item in the list`

Comment: @GiladRaz you also have an error when your duplicate the string, the size must be `strlen(strlen(tempStr) + 1`, I again edited my answer

Comment: @GiladRaz is it ok ?

Comment: i'm still trying to figure out exactly what you mean because it's a lot though i am fixing it now thanks to you. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @GiladRaz I edited to put at the end the full modified code

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it!

Comment: @GiladRaz BTW, you do not defined a _list_ but a _vector_ ;-)